# A member viable not getting populated by @Input class variable

Tags: angular, typescript

New to Angular. I have not been able to find the reason why the value of the userName variable is not getting assigned to user.myName. Ideas?

**address-card.component.ts**

```
        export class AddressCardComponent implements OnInit {

  user: any;
  @Input('name') userName: string;
  @Input('jobTitle') myTitle: string;

  constructor() {
    this.user = {
      myName: this.userName,
      title: this.myTitle,
      address: '123 Main St., Somewhere, USA',
      phone: [
        '321-555-5550',
        '321-555-8319',
        '321-555-5088'
      ]    
    }
   }
```

**address-card.component.html**

```
<div>
<h1>***{{user.myName}}XXX</h1>
<h3>{{user.title}}</h3>
<p>{{user.address}}</p>
<div>
  <p>Phone</p>
  <p *ngFor="let phoneNumber of user.phone">{{phoneNumber}}</p>
</div>
<p>{{userName}}</p>
</div>
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-address-card name="John Doe" jobTitle="Manager"></app-address-card>
```

The h1 tag output is just ***XXX

Answer (score 2):

`Constructor` is not the right place to use `@Input` values!

angular components have life cycle and `constructor` is not lifecycle method. May be at the time `constructor` executed, the `@input` value is not set.

So implements `OnInit` and set the value in `ngOnInit()`

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.user = {
      myName: this.userName,
      title: this.myTitle,
      address: '123 Main St., Somewhere, USA',
      phone: [
        '321-555-5550',
        '321-555-8319',
        '321-555-5088'
      ]    
    }
   }
```

You can also use `OnChanges` and see what that value changed and catch that.